# Let $E = C[0, 1]$ and $A = \{f \in E \mid f(x) > 0 \text{ for all } 0 \leqslant x \leqslant 1 \}$. Is $A$ open when the norm of $E$ is the L1-norm?

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces

> Let $E = C[0, 1]$ and $A = \{f \in E \mid f(x) > 0 \text{ for all } 0 \leqslant x \leqslant 1 \}$. Is $A$ open when the norm of $E$ is the L1-norm?

Let $f \in A$. Now I have $B(f,r)= \{g \in A \mid d(f,g) < r \}.$ Let $g \in B(f,r)$ now I think it would satisfy to show that $g$ outputs only positive values in order to show that it belongs to $A$ which would imply that $B(f,r) \subset A$? Using the  $L1$ norm I have $$d(f,g) = |f(x) -g(x)|$$ but I cannot seem to show from here that $g$ would be positive?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\epsilon>0$. If $f \in A$ is a continuous positive function, we know that there exists $M$ such that $f(x)\leq M$.  Thus, we know that there exists $\delta$ such that $$\int_{1-\delta} ^1 f \leq \epsilon/2M$$. Define the function $g$ as
$g(x)= f(x)$ if $x \leq 1-\delta$ and connect $f(1-\delta)$ to zero via a line with domain $[1-\delta,1]$, this function is continuous. Now, note that $d(f,g) < \epsilon$ and that $g(x)=0$. Thus, any open ball containing$f$ is not contained in $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f_n(x)=nx$ if $0 \leq x \leq \frac  1n$ and $f_n(x)=1$ if $\frac 1 n < x \leq 1$. Let $f(x)=1$ for all $x$. Then it is easy to check that $(f_n)$ is  sequence in $A^{c}$ conveging in the $L_1$ norm to $f$ but $f$ belongs to $A$. It follows that $A^{c}$ is not closed, so $A$ is not open.